# A Flow embeded in VF Page doesn't work in Community Portal

Tags: visualforce, portal, flow

We want to use a Flow  in our Community portal.

I created a flow, activated it, embeded into VF page, created a Tab for that page and in Portal settings switched the Tab to right, thus now the Tab is available on Portal Home layout (and made that VFP be available for Site, just in case).

And when I am in the Portal (under Admin profile), I can click on that Tab and see very first screen of my Flow and can hit 'Next' button. After that, insteed of second screen (or first screen again if didnt pick a required field) I see "Error: Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page"  :(

But within an Org those Tab, VFP and Flow work well.

Not sure what to do...

Thanks

Comment: Is security on the VF pages set for access from your Community and for it's users? Ditto for the objects those pages use in terms of FLS, profiles, etc?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have opened an access to that VFP and an object (and its fields) for my custom Community profile. And I have "Data Not Available" on that Tab in Portal. (for example, my Portal user can access  and edit that object's records on their standard layout with no problem). But even if I go to Portal like an admin, I see only first screen of the Flow, and instead of second screen - " Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page".

Comment: PS: my portal user in Dev Org has no Flow License and it is impossible to activate for his profile Permission "Run Force.com Flow". That is probably reason why my Portal user can not get it. But admin user has a Permission "Manage Force.com Flow". So it is still mystery why it does not work for him if to go into Portal directly from Portal settings.

Comment: Is the error "Data Not Available" or "Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page?"

Comment: Also, can you post your VF page code so we can see what else is going on there?

Comment: Hi! I have a message "Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page" when I go to Community Portal under my regular admin account. There is almost nothing on that VF page: <apex:page >
<flow:interview name="Create_Application"/>
</apex:page>